# Why is the interceptor not called in the same service class?

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, weld

I want to use interceptors in a Java-SE application and I am using weld as CDI implementation and i'm testing this here:

**The Main-Class:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    WeldContainer weldContainer = new Weld().initialize();

    Service service = weldContainer.instance().select(Service.class).get();
    service.methodCall();
    service.methodCallNumberTwo();

}
```

**The Service-Class:**

```
  public class Service {

    @TestAnnotation
    public void methodCall(){

      System.out.println("methodCall...!");
      methodCallNumberTwo();

    }

    @TestAnnotation
    public void methodCallNumberTwo(){

      System.out.println("methodCallNumberTwo...!");

    }

 }
```

**The Interceptor-Class:**

```
 @Interceptor
 @TestAnnotation
 public class TestInterceptor {

     @AroundInvoke
     public Object interceptorMethod(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {

         System.out.println("I'm the TestInterceptor of "+invocationContext.getMethod());

         return invocationContext.proceed();

     }

 }
```

**Aaaand the output:**

```
 I'm the TestInterceptor of public void Service.methodCall()
 methodCall...!
 methodCallNumberTwo...!
 I'm the TestInterceptor of public void Service.methodCallNumberTwo()
 methodCallNumberTwo...!
```

**My Questions**

First: Why isn't the interceptor called in methodCall() when i'm calling methodCallNumberTwo()?

Second: Is there a way to change that?

I'm only studying the behavior of interceptors and want to understand. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java CDI. Interceptor is only invoked in the first method call in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129910/java-cdi-interceptor-is-only-invoked-in-the-first-method-call-in-a-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interceptor is not called because you are calling it on the same instance of the object. If you're familiar with EJBs it's the same as calling a method on the same object instead of through the EJB context.

If you debug through it you'll notic that the method call on the injected objects goes through a proxy. The method call from methodOne to methodTwo isn't proxied.

Comment: Is this in the CDI spec somewhere?  I looked to find a reference to Interceptors only being called via the Proxy objects, but was unable to find anything in the spec.

Comment: I don't think it'll be in the spec. My guess would to take a look at the EJB spec and any of the other supporting specs.