# CDI: Interceptor is not invoked when called from a JUnit test

Tags: java, jboss, weld, weld-se

I have created an interceptor following the [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html).

To test the interceptor, I put:

```java
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionalInterceptor {
  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("intercept!");
    return ctx.proceed();
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to test this interceptor in a unit test, using [the WeldJUnit4Runner class](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingUnitTestsWithWeldAndJunit4).

```java
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  @Transactional  // the interceptor I created
  public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("testMethod");
    anotherMethod();
  }

  @Transactional
  public void anotherMethod() {
    System.out.println("anotherMethod");
  }
}
```

Now the expected output would of course be

```
intercept!
testMethod
intercept!
anotherMethod
```

But instead, the output is

```
intercept!
testMethod
anotherMethod
```

The main problem is that this is also true if I inject a bean into my test: The first method of the bean that I call gets intercepted, but if this method calls another method, the interceptor is not invoked.

Any ideas at all are much appreciated!

---

I just tried to modify my code as suggested by @adrobisch, and this works:

```java
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyTest {
  @Inject
  private MyTest instance;

  @Test
  @Transactional  // the interceptor I created
  public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("testMethod");
    instance.anotherMethod();
  }

  @Transactional
  public void anotherMethod() {
    System.out.println("anotherMethod");
  }
}
```

The output is (as expected)

```
intercept!
testMethod
intercept!
anotherMethod
```

**However**, the following does **not** work:

```java
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyTest {
  @Inject
  private MyTest instance;

  @Test
  // @Transactional  <- no interceptor here!
  public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("testMethod");
    instance.anotherMethod();
  }

  @Transactional
  public void anotherMethod() {
    System.out.println("anotherMethod");
  }
}
```

The output here is

```
testMethod
anotherMethod
```

This seems to be according to spec, however! Everything is fine now.

Comment: I did some research on the behavior in your edit, and I think from the CDI perspective the invocation of `anotherMethod` from `testMethod` is seen as a business method invocation so interceptors are not applied. See https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi-spec.org/blob/master/_faq/core/104-when-are-interceptors-and-decorators-applied.asciidoc for further reference and a link to the CDI spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interceptors are implemented using proxies. Since the second method is called from within the object instance, the call can't be catched by the proxy and so it can't be intercepted. You would need a reference to the CDI proxy of your bean to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using this information, I also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628405/why-is-the-interceptor-not-called-in-the-same-service-class) about the same issue. Do you happen to know a tool of some kind that can inform about places in the source code where these incorrect method calls are used?

Comment: I would not call these invocations incorrect, they are just a business method invocations inside you beans. It would be very difficult for a tool to detect these invocations (thinking about interfaces where interceptor annotations are missing etc.) so you just have to think about where you want to apply interceptors and create client beans accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to run tests on a properly-initialized CDI bean with DeltaSpike, although it's documentation and error messages aren't very helpful when it's not exactly right. This is how to do it to get the @Transactional interceptor to work:

```
@Transactional // the @Transactional from org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction
@TestControl(startScopes = { TransactionScoped.class })
@RunWith(CdiTestRunner.class)
public MyTestClass { ... }
```

then add:

```
deltaspike.testcontrol.use_test_class_as_cdi_bean=true
```

to src/test/resources/META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties

Unfortunately, @Transactional(readOnly = true) doesn't work - no idea why. And, unlike the Spring equivalent, it won't roll back the transaction, or run @Before/@After in the same transaction.

But for another interceptor you only need around the test method itself it should be fine.

Comment: TestControl just controls std. CDI-Contexts.
@Transactional(readOnly = true) can't work if you think you need to handle TransactionScoped via TestControl, because in that case the interceptor which handles both is just not active. If you are using Weld, please ensure that you enable the transaction-interceptor in the test-module as well...